# Cloud Foundry on OpenStack for a private / on-premise cloud

Tags: cloud, openstack, paas, cloud-foundry

I am looking for information regarding minimum hardware requirements to install Cloud Foundry on OpenStack to set up a private / on premise cloud. So far I have come across the following in the documentation for PCF –

https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-7/customizing/openstack.html#prereq

> Your OpenStack tenant must have the following resources before you
> install Pivotal Cloud Foundry:
>
> - 118 GB of RAM
> - 22 available instances
> - 16 small VMs (1 vCPU, 1024 MB of RAM, 10 GB of root disk)
> - 3 large VMs (4 vCPU, 16384 MB of RAM, 10 GB of root disk)
> - 3 extra-large VMs (8 vCPU, 16 GB of RAM, 160 GB of ephemeral disk)
> - 56 vCPUs 1 TB of storage
> - Neutron networking with floating IP

**However, I would like to know how much of the aforementioned resources are consumed by OpenStack, how much by PCF and how much is left over for setting up my own PaaS!?**

Answer (score 0):

This is the configuration requirements from OpenStack tenant side to run your own PaaS, excluding any OpenStack overhead.

3 extra-large VM's are the ones allocated for Diego Cells, so you can estimate that it is the size available to your PaaS applications.

It is easily scalable with PCF and actual memory/disk available to your applications can be increased with overcommit settings per http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-9/customizing/openstack-er-config.html#advanced

Answer (score 0):

### Documentation

First look at [the flavors definitions](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-deployment/blob/master/iaas-support/openstack/README.md#prerequisites)

You can customize:

- Cloud config [`cloud-config.yml`](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-deployment/blob/master/iaas-support/openstack/cloud-config.yml)
- CF deployment manifest [`cf-deployment.yml`](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-deployment/blob/master/cf-deployment.yml)

### Example of requirements for a minimal DEV environment

VCPUs: 31, RAM: 116 GB, Disk: 392 GB

```
Instance          Flavor                               VCPUs  RAM (MB)  Disk (GB)  Load (1m, 5m, 15m)  CPU User  CPU Sys  CPU Wait  Memory Usage  System Disk Usage  Ephemeral Disk Usage  Persistent Disk Usage
api               small-50GB-ephemeral-disk            2        7680    53         0.03, 0.07, 0.08    2.6%      1.6%     0.1%      31% (2.4 GB)   39% (31i%)        3% (1i%)              -
blobstore         small                                2        7680    17         0.04, 0.03, 0.00    0.3%      0.5%     0.0%      4% (281 MB)    39% (31i%)        3% (1i%)              4% (0i%)
cc-worker         minimal                              1        3840    13         0.05, 0.02, 0.00    1.8%      1.5%     0.1%      13% (484 MB)   39% (31i%)        11% (8i%)             -
consul            minimal                              1        3840    13         0.01, 0.10, 0.06    1.6%      1.5%     0.4%      3% (120 MB)    39% (31i%)        3% (1i%)              1% (0i%)
diego-api         small                                2        7680    17         0.08, 0.07, 0.02    1.2%      1.7%     0.0%      2% (168 MB)    39% (31i%)        4% (1i%)              -
diego-cell        small-highmem-100GB-ephemeral-disk   4        31232   103        0.39, 0.37, 0.50    3.7%      4.7%     0.0%      35% (11 GB)    39% (31i%)        27% (4i%)             -
doppler           minimal                              1        3840    13         0.00, 0.01, 0.00    1.7%      3.0%     0.0%      5% (186 MB)    39% (31i%)        4% (1i%)              -
etcd              minimal                              1        3840    13         0.14, 0.05, 0.01    0.7%      1.8%     1.0%      5% (172 MB)    39% (31i%)        5% (2i%)              6% (0i%)
log-api           sharedcpu                            1        2048    13         0.00, 0.03, 0.00    1.0%      2.1%     0.0%      7% (137 MB)    39% (31i%)        3% (1i%)              -
mysql             small                                2        7680    17         0.13, 0.09, 0.03    0.9%      0.8%     0.7%      18% (1.4 GB)   39% (31i%)        20% (4i%)             27% (0i%)
nats              minimal                              1        3840    13         0.03, 0.03, 0.00    0.5%      0.8%     0.0%      3% (114 MB)    39% (31i%)        3% (1i%)              -
router            minimal                              1        3840    13         0.00, 0.02, 0.00    0.8%      1.0%     0.0%      4% (133 MB)    41% (31i%)        3% (1i%)              -
scheduler         minimal                              1        3840    13         0.00, 0.00, 0.00    1.7%      1.0%     0.0%      11% (432 MB)   39% (31i%)        13% (8i%)             -
syslog-scheduler  minimal                              1        3840    13         0.04, 0.03, 0.00    0.6%      1.0%     0.0%      3% (116 MB)    39% (31i%)        3% (1i%)              -
tcp-router        minimal                              1        3840    13         0.00, 0.00, 0.00    0.6%      1.1%     0.0%      3% (132 MB)    39% (31i%)        4% (1i%)              -
uaa               minimal                              1        3840    13         0.04, 0.10, 0.04    1.1%      1.3%     0.4%      16% (590 MB)   39% (31i%)        11% (1i%)             -
bosh              m1.xlarge                            8        16384   42
```